# convert String to Date javascript o Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need convert string "Nov  1 2018 11:07AM" to date, before compare with Date.Now and extract to minutes difference, can you help me?

Comment: Will that date always be in that format?

Comment: Yes, this value always this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
var strDate = 'Nov 5 2018 12:55AM'
var arrDate = strDate.split(' ')
arrDate[arrDate.length -1] = convert(arrDate[arrDate.length -1])
var newstrDate = arrDate.join(' ')
var date = new Date(newstrDate)
var today = new Date()
var diffMs = date - today // milliseconds between now and the custom date
var diffMins = Math.round((diffMs / 1000) / 60); // minutes until the custom date
console.log(diffMins)

function convert(hours) {
    var type = hours.indexOf('PM') == -1 ? 'AM' : 'PM'
    hours = hours.replace(type,'')
    var dictionary = {
    01: '13',
    02: '14',
    03: '15',
    04: '16',
    05: '17',
    06: '18',
    07: '19',
    08: '20',
    09: '21',
    10: '22',
    11: '23',
    12: '24'
  }

  if(type == 'PM'){
    var arrHours = hours.split(':')
    arrHours[0] = dictionary[arrHours[0]]
    hours = arrHours.join(':')
  }
  return hours
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For date manipulation go for `moments.js` library (https://momentjs.com/).

A basic example of converting you date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

```js
var m = moment('Nov 1 2018 11:07AM',"MMM DD YYYY hh:mmA");
console.log(m.format('YYYY-MM-DD')); // 2018-11-01
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```